# Auto increment text box value on dynamically generated table rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am populating max + 1 serial number from database to a text box in table row which can be dynamically generated into multiple rows. As a result I need the serial number to auto increase and decrease when adding and deleting rows.
Here are my codes:

PHP

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    $selectQuery = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT MAX(SlNo) AS MaxSerial FROM cashsheet");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectQuery)){
        $serialNumber = $row['MaxSerial'];
        $maxSerial = $serialNumber + 1;
    } 
?>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="serial[]" value="<?php echo $maxSerial; ?>"></td>
```

And this is my javascript to dynamically add rows into the table.

```
var $tr = $('table.dynamicTable tr.cloneme:first').clone();

    addDP($('input.datepicker'));

    $('#addMore').on('click',function(){
        var clone = $tr.clone();
        console.log(clone);
        clone.append("<td><button class='deleteAdded btn btn-danger hvr-float-shadow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span>Remove</button></td>");
        addDP(clone.find('input.datepicker'));
        $('table.dynamicTable').append(clone);

    });
    $(document).on('click','.deleteAdded',function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

Can somebody please tell me how to go about doing this. I Googled a lot but couldn't find anything. Thank you

Comment: you can maintain a variable which will hold the total rows, every time you click add increment this counter and assign to your row..

Comment: also you can take a look at `css counters`, may be they can solve your problem.